# How can vue-router push({name:"question"}) with hash?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

eg: the changed route is  https://stackoverflow.com/question#hello

router.push(location, onComplete?, onAbort?) 
name is required in localtion

Comment: Does `router.push({ name: 'question', hash: 'hello' })` not work?

Comment: It really doesn't work. Please see https://codepen.io/vigdxx/pen/ZMrMXL/ @Decade Moon

Comment: router.push({ name: 'question', hash: '#hello' } can work, # is must

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Vue Router allows you to completely customize the scroll behavior on route navigation. Vue scroll behavior is a wide topic, so you can dive into [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling)

For your example I think you need hash prop, with scroll behavior:

```
Router.push({ name: routeName, hash: '#toHash' })
```

Answer (score 2):

`router.push({ name: 'question', hash: '#hello' })` can work

Answer (score 1):

For `Router.push({ name: routeName, hash: '#toHash' })` to work, you need to configure your vue router.

```js
// router.js file
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    // Your Routes
  ],
  // Ref: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      // This ensures that if hash is provided to router.push it works as expected.
      //  & since we have used "behavior: 'smooth'" the browser will slowly come to this hash position.
      return {
        el: to.hash,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This code assumes you are using vue-router v4.